# TypeError when creating Snakemake report (v5.30.1)

Tags: python, snakemake

I have an error while creating a report with snakemake (5.30.1). The pipeline works well, the error is raised with the `--report` argument:

Command line used while running the pipeline:

```
snakemake -s /mnt/beegfs/pipelines/rna-count-salmon/Snakefile --profile /mnt/beegfs/pipelines/rna-count-salmon/.igr/profile/slurm  --cache salmon_index tr2gene
```

Command line used while creating the report:

```
snakemake -s /mnt/beegfs/pipelines/rna-count-salmon/Snakefile --profile /mnt/beegfs/pipelines/rna-count-salmon/.igr/profile/slurm --report Quantification_Report.html --cache salmon_index tr2gene
```

The error I have *only while reporting*:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/beegfs/userdata/t_dayris/anaconda3/envs/rna-count-salmon/lib/python3.8/site-packages/snakemake/__init__.py", line 687, in snakemake
    success = workflow.execute(
  File "/mnt/beegfs/userdata/t_dayris/anaconda3/envs/rna-count-salmon/lib/python3.8/site-packages/snakemake/workflow.py", line 820, in execute
    auto_report(dag, report, stylesheet=report_stylesheet)
  File "/mnt/beegfs/userdata/t_dayris/anaconda3/envs/rna-count-salmon/lib/python3.8/site-packages/snakemake/report/__init__.py", line 722, in auto_report
    rec.starttime = min(rec.starttime, meta["starttime"])
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

The error is not raised if I run the pipeline **within** the snakemake-pipeline's repository. I have used this profile in the past (without any error) and created reports without any error with snakemake version 5.27.0 and previous ones.

If I delete the `.snakemake` repository within the working directory, then the error is solved. If anyone could point out what I am doing wrong, or giving me advice to help me investigate on the error, it would be great.

Thanks in advance

**Edit**: Disabling the `--cache` option did not fix the issue, cf. comment of Dmitry Kuzminov

**Edit2**: I am 100% positive, the error comes from the repository `.snakemake/metadata`. I am now trying to identify the issue within this file.

Comment: Do you mean that you deleted *cache* files (the temporary files that Snakemake creates in the folder)?

Comment: Hi, no, i deleted the repository `.snakemake`, however, you are right! my cache directory (located elsewhere) is empty while it should not. I'll investigate in that direction, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is now known and fixed: https://github.com/snakemake/snakemake/pull/805